# AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException with Basic Authentication with Spring Rest Service

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, basic-authentication

I got AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException running my Spring Rest Service which should be secured with basic authentication. This leads to HTTP 500 instead of the expected 403.
Anything missing in the configuration?

My Spring security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

My Spring config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.dummy"})
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({MySecurityConfig.class})
public class MySpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("springDispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(0);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(MySpringConfig.class);
        return context;
    }
}
```

My secured Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dummy")
public class MyController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpEntity<?> doSomething() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

My failing Test **(actual: 500, expected: 403)**:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MySpringConfig.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext context;

    protected MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        new TestContextManager(getClass()).prepareTestInstance(this);
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void doDummy_not_authorized_403() throws Exception {
        final MockHttpServletResponse response = this.mvc.perform(post("/dummy")).andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print()).andReturn().getResponse();
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), equalTo(403));
    }
}
```